# Calculate age in days/months/years in OpenOffice

Tags: worksheet-function, date-time, openoffice-calc

In need to find the age in days - months - years in OpenOffice.

There is `DATEDIF()` in Microsoft Excel. You can use it to find the difference in days/months/years between two dates.

```
Age Calculation 
    You can calculate a persons age based on their birthday and todays date.
    The calculation uses the DATEDIF() function.        
    The DATEDIF() is not documented in Excel 5, 7 or 97, but it is in 2000. 
    (Makes you wonder what else Microsoft forgot to tell us!)   
    Birth date :    01-Jan-60       
    Years lived :   52   =DATEDIF(C8,TODAY(),"y")   
    and the months :    4    =DATEDIF(C8,TODAY(),"ym")
    and the days :  30   =DATEDIF(C8,TODAY(),"md")
```

One can calculate by below formula, but it is cumbersome to calculate months.

```
Another way to calculate age         
This method gives you an age which may potentially have decimal places representing the months.
If the age is 20.5, the .5 represents 6 months.             
Birth date :    01-Jan-60
Age is :    52.41    =(TODAY()-C23)/365.25
```

Comment: Did you check your post's formatting before you submitted it? Please check the preview area.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`YEARS()`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_YEARS_function) and [`MONTHS()`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MONTHS_function) function from the set of [Date/Time functions](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Date_&_Time_functions):

```
=YEARS(01-Jan-60,NOW,1)
```

and

```
=MONTHS(01-Jan-60,NOW,1)
```

will give you the sum of years and months elapsed. To get the remainder months from the years sum, just use modulo (in Calc: [`MOD()`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MOD_function)):

```
=MOD(MONTHS(01-Jan-60,NOW,1), 12)
```

will return the remaining 4 months after dividing the total sum of months by 12.

Of course, you can replace the dates that are included in the formulas above by cell references. `=YEARS(A1,A2,1)` assumes that cells A1 and A2 contain dates.